# How Can Add "Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Projects" to Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, nuget

It seems that the download manager has lost the download link. Is this normal and what can I do now?

Is there another source for this package: [Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 Installer Projects](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=visualstudioclient.MicrosoftVisualStudio2017InstallerProjects)?

[image: remote name error]

Comment: You really should let it die peacefully https://blog.lextudio.com/the-horrible-facts-on-visual-studio-setup-projects-45e66fe86d8d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can download it, open `Developer Command Prompt for VS 2017` and use the following statement to install it.

```
VSIXInstaller <path to vsix file>
```

Comment: The problem is i can't download it  i want find it on internet all is dead links >> ~~!!!!

Comment: @AhmedKamal In my test, I can download "InstallerProjects.vsix" successfully through the link you provided.

Comment: can you upload it for me ?

Comment: @AhmedKamal You can download vsix [here](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AqgLs2tdMyFNg381xY-KRebGCaU6?e=m9Gscp).